# R: function to create a list of subset/smaller dataframes from a existing larger dataframe according to date

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop, subset

I am starting with a large dataframe. I would like to divide this into smaller dataframes. I have created a function to do this in a loop

This is function code in R

```
getPortfolios <- function(n) {
  i = 1
  listofdfs <- list()

  for (i in 1:n) {
    df <- data.frame(subset(df_log_returns, mdy(row.names(df_log_returns)) >= var$var[i] & mdy(row.names(df_log_returns)) <= var$var[i]))
    listofdfs[[i]] <- list(df)
  }
  return(listofdfs)
}
```

when I run `getPortfolio(1)` and call `listofdfs[1]` I get the error `Error: object 'listofdfs' not found`

This is particularly puzzling bc when I run this as a simple loop:

```
listofdfs <- list()
n <- 16
for (i in 1:n) {
  df <- data.frame(subset(df_log_returns, mdy(row.names(df_log_returns)) >= var$var[i] & mdy(row.names(df_log_returns)) <= var$var[i]))
  listofdfs[[i]] <- df
}
```

`listofdfs` can be called...hmmmmm so puzzling...

Comment: *listofdfs* only exists within the scope of function not your global environment unlike second code block. Why are you commenting out the `return` line? Typically, you would then call: `listofdfs <- getPortfolio(1)`

Comment: ah....I guess I was calling it wrong...
I commented return out bc I was playing around as to what was going on...

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
listofdfs <- getPortfolio(*)`
```

instead of

```
getPortfolio(*)
```